# Flutter/Firebase : Authenticated with same account on different devices

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my Flutter app, I integrated Firebase Auth and it works fine.

When the user is logged in the app, he can close the app in background and open it again, he will still be logged in. In `main.dart`, here's the home navigation :

```
    home: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser == null
            ? Login()
            : MainPage(),
```

So the only way for the user to logout is to actually log out in the app or uninstall the app.

But I'm facing an issue : The user can be logged with the same account but from different devices. I want the user to log in only one device at a time.

So basically, when the user is logged in device 1 and tries to log in device 2, he should be automatically logged out from device 1 with a message like 'you lost connection, please authenticate again'.

I haven't found contents regarding this issue, and I don't know how to pull this off.